# How to solve the following linearly independent vector problem?

Tags: vector-spaces, independence

$A=\{a_1,\ldots,a_r\}$ & $B=\{b_1,\ldots,b_s\}$ are sets of linearly independent vectors. Each $a_j (j=1,\ldots,r)$ can be written as a linear combination of vectors in $B$, and each $b_i (i =1,\ldots,r)$  can be written as a linear combination of vectors in $A$.

How to show that there exists $b \in B$ s.t. the following holds. The set $A' = \{a_1,\ldots,a_{r-1},b\}$ obtained by replacing $a_r$ in $A$ with $b$ is linearly independent, and each $b_i (i =1,\ldots,s)$ is  a linear combination of vectors in $A'$.

Answer:
I know that, since $A$ & $B$ are sets with linearly independent vectors, we have,
$$\sum_{j=1}^r c_j a_j =0$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^s d_i b_i =0$$
All $c_j=0, d_i=0$

$$a_j=\sum_{i=1}^s e_i b_i$$
$$b_i=\sum_{j=1}^r f_j a_j$$

How can I solve the above problem?

Answer (score 0):

You do not say if you already know about bases and dimension. Here
is a solution that uses those concepts.

Because of the hypotheses, the subspace spanned by $A$ is the
same as the subspace spanned by $B$. Call this subspace $V$. Then
the dimension of $V$ is $r=s$.

Next, denote by $W$ the subspace of $V$ spanned by
$a_1,\ldots,a_{r-1}$. Then $W$ has dimension $r-1$, so $W\neq V$.
It follows that not all the elements of $B$ are in $W$ (otherwise
the subspace spanned by $B$ would be included in $W$). So some
element of $B$ is not in $W$ - call it $b$.

Then $A' = \{a_1,\ldots,a_{r-1},b\}$ is linearly independent
and has $r$ elements, so it is another basis of $V$. This concludes
the proof.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was little bit confused. Because in the second part of this question I have to show that $r=s$. Then I thought that we cannot use it in the first part.

Comment: Can we say that $A$ spans $B$ since each $b_i$ can be written as a linear combination of the vectors in $A$?